# How combine two rows of same id using group by with sum of dynamically created columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

How combine two rows of same id using group by with sum of dynamically created columns.Basic,Esi is dynamically created columns.we can't determine that column names and no of such columns

```
employeeId  Basic  ESI 

117         NULL   3000
117         2000   NULL
118         NULL   4000
118         1000   NULL
```

i need a output like

```
employeeId  Basic  ESI 

117         2000   3000
118         1000   4000
```

Comment: what you need is magic ;)  if there is absolutely NO WAY  (i don't think so) to determine which columns you need you will not be able to do a query!?!?

Answer (score 1):

Only way of doing this is dynamic sql:

TestTable and testdata

```
CREATE TABLE xxx
(employeeId int, Basic int,  ESI int, abc int)

INSERT xxx values 
(117,NULL,3000,1),
(117,2000,NULL,1),
(118,NULL,4000,1),
(118,1000,NULL,1)
go
```

Query:

```
DECLARE @colnames nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @tablename nvarchar(256)= '[xxx]' -- assuming you know the tablename


SELECT @colnames = coalesce(@colnames + ',', '') 
      + 'sum(['+ name + '])' + '['+ name + ']' 
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = 
  (SELECT object_id from sys.tables 
   WHERE
     name = 'xxx')
     and name not in ('employeeId')

SET @sql = 'SELECT employeeId,' + @colnames + 'FROM ' 
           + @tablename + ' GROUP BY employeeId'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Result:

```
employeeId  Basic  ESI   abc
117         2000   3000  2
118         1000   4000  2
```

Answer (score 0):

@t-clausen.dk beat me to it, but here's my less elegant, nasty solution added for the sake of it, given I have done the work:

```
--Test Data
CREATE TABLE #Source
(employeeId int, [Basic] int,  ESI int)

INSERT #Source values 
 (117,NULL,3000)
,(117,2000,NULL)
,(118,NULL,4000)
,(118,1000,NULL)



CREATE TABLE #Results
(employeeId INT, [Basic] INT, ESI Int, abc INT)

INSERT #Results(employeeId) SELECT DISTINCT employeeId FROM #Source

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ThisCol VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @Curses CURSOR

SET @Curses = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Col.name
    FROM
                tempdb.sys.columns Col
    INNER JOIN  tempdb.sys.tables Tab   ON Col.object_id = Tab.object_id
    WHERE
        Tab.name LIKE '#Source%'
    AND Col.name NOT IN ('Employeeid') -- list of ignored columns

OPEN @Curses
FETCH NEXT FROM @Curses INTO @ThisCol
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
SET @SQL = 
'MERGE #Results AS Tgt
USING (SELECT employeeID, SUM(ISNULL('+ @ThisCol +',0)) AS MyCol FROM #Source GROUP BY employeeId) AS Src   ON Tgt.employeeId = Src.employeeId
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Tgt.' + @ThisCol + ' = Src.MyCol;'

EXEC (@SQL)
PRINT @SQL
FETCH NEXT FROM @Curses INTO @ThisCol
END
CLOSE @Curses
DEALLOCATE @Curses
SELECT * FROM #Results

DROP TABLE #Source
DROP TABLE #Results
```

I'd take the other solution if I were you! :)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `ISNULL` function, then assign 0 if `NULL` and then use `GROUP BY`

Try this:

```
    SELECT employeeId
           , SUM(ISNULL([Basic],0)) AS 'SumOfBasic'
           , SUM(ISNULL([ESI],0)) AS 'SumOfESI' 
    FROM TableName GROUP BY employeeId
```

Comment: We does'nt knw about its column name is basic or not ,its a payhead,names are creating dynamically .

Comment: @ShamseerKSmr , in that case there's no direct way to do that.. but my answer above will help you to do the summation.